# Change Gitlab work-tree default location

Tags: git, bash, gitlab

Our server is hosting both Gitlab and apache on Ubuntu 14.04 and they're ok.
I am using the following post-receive hook bash script to auto-deploy websites for every push:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
if [$ref=~.*/masters]; then
git --work-tree=/var/www/html
git checkout -f
fi
done
```

To my suprise nothing is happening- There is nothing in /var/www/html. The git client succeeds but it also outputs git command options as if there is something wrong with git --work-tree.

By the way where does Gitlab store the working directory files because when I run this command on the server

```
sudo -u git -H ls /home/git/repositories/root/demogitlab.git
```

I can not see them. I can see config, HEAD,Hooks,Objects and refs.

Answer (score 0):

You **need** spaces around `[`, `=~`, and `]`. They aren't optional.

`git --work-tree` **isn't** a valid command by itself. `--work-tree` is an *option* to other `git` sub-commands.

```
git --work-tree checkout -f
```